# The request was rejected because its size (5838334) exceeds the configured maximum (2097152)

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I want to handle org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException

My application.properties file contains :

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=2MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=2MB
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
```

I have tried handling the exception using following code :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerRestController
{
    @ExceptionHandler(FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException.class)
     public ResponseEntity<Object>exceptionHandler(FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>("size limit exceeded",new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
  }
}
```

Though I have handled the exception, I am getting an exception

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] 
threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse 
multipart servlet request; org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (5838334) exceeds the configured maximum (2097152)
```

How can I customize above class to handle the exception ?

Comment: I have a similar issue. The request is rejected. My Interceptor is logging it and returning a well defined result which should lead to an error-jsp (as defined in struts.xml) but instead i get "page not found". I think its because of that rejected request. But how do I get it staying alive to follow my struts-navigation and not to becoming a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved problem using following code

```java
    @ExceptionHandler(MultipartException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE)
    public ApiError multipartExceptionHandler(MultipartException e)
    {
        Throwable th = e.getCause();
        if( th instanceof IllegalStateException )
        {
            Throwable cause = th.getCause();
            if(cause instanceof  SizeLimitExceededException)
            {
                SizeLimitExceededException ex = (SizeLimitExceededException) cause;
                return new ApiError(HttpStatus.PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE.value(),"Total size of file(s) should not be more than " + (int)(ex.getPermittedSize()/Math.pow(2, 20)) + " MB");
            }
        }
        return new ApiError(HttpStatus.PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE.value(),e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the container configuration, if you're using tomcat, update `server.xml` file with the following config

```xml
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" 
           port="8080" 
           protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           redirectPort="8443" 
           maxPostSize="52428800" />
```

Set maxPostSize to 52428800 increase the upload file size to 50 MB. By default it's set to 2 MB.

For more explanation, read this: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

Comment: Upload file size limit is not my concern. I want to handle the situation where specified limit exceeds.